# Issue in date comparison in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, date

I have MySQL with below settings
Server version: 5.0.77
MySQL client version: 5.0.41
Protocol version: 10
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
MySQL connection collation: utf8_unicode_ci

I am just doing a simple query and it returned wrong
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE mydate >= '2010-08-30'

Today is 8/30 and I have 1 row with mydate is '2010-06-01' and that row was selected. Why?
If I do this, it returns zero record which is correct
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE mydate >= NOW()

The first query was executed correctly in local but not live server.

How do I go about troubleshooting this? Is it because of different MySQL version, time setting, server setting... What am I looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the data type of the `mydate` column?

Comment: mydate is a VARCHAR(15). That should be OK right? It works local.

Comment: No, it's not OK. it should be of date type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MYSQL you should not use single quotes '' around your date, this causes the MYSQL server to interpret your entry as a string rather than a date.  I would also suggest using date() around your date entry in the database to ensure that it is indeed a date.

Here is an example of how I would perform your above query in MYSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE date(mydate) >= (2010-08-30)
```

This query should return your desired results.

Comment: If you do not use quotes around a date, like in your example, then [MySQL will interpret it as an arithmetic expression](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/41316) (2010 minus 8 minus 30).

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a manifestation of a bug in MySQL that was fixed in versions >= 5.0.50. I believe that the bug only exhibits when there is an index on the date column.

See this [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31221) for details.

This may not be the bug you are experiencing, but nevertheless it seems very likely that the root cause of your problem is a MySQL bug that has been fixed in one version but not the others. I would advise that you bring the two versions of the database in line.

Comment: Are you talking about the server version? Current one is 5.0.77. So what else causing the problem? Or do you mean to make the client version to be 5.0.77 as well?

Comment: You need to start eliminating differences between local and server to narrow down the possible causes of the problem. Usually, it's easier to mess with local, so I'd start by making the client version 5.0.77 and seeing if the problem manifests itself there.